# WSO2 APIM is there a way to disable the certificate requirements of the endpoints?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638) ~[?:?]
        ... 82 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:127) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129) ~[?:?]
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638) ~[?:?]
        ... 82 more
```

I'm deploying multiple APIs with different endpoints in our internal environment. I can't find a fix or bypass to certificate requirement. I hope I find a workaround it even if its unethical or any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the certificates of your endpoints to the truststore.

Just access the endpoint through the browser and save the certificate. You can add it to the truststore using either third-party tooling like keystoreexporer or the built-in commandline JAVA keytool.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/security/configuring-keystores/configuring-keystores-in-wso2-api-manager/